# Error Handling with Excel VBA controlling Word and PDF

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

TL DR version: what errors should I specifically look for in a error handler with an excel vba running a word template and saving as word doco and pdf.

For the first time, I am actually giving a macro spreadsheet to someone excel literate, but macro illiterate.

This spreadsheet basically opens a bunch of word templates, changes some bookmarks, saves as a word document and as a PDF.

I cannot afford for this spreadsheet to fail, which brings me to error handling.

I haven't really pushed into error handling too much previously. But I have come up with a list of possible errors the 3rd party could run into

> Invalid Inputs (various)
>   Cannot find word templates
>   Cannot find bookmarks
>   Cannot Save As Word (various reasons)
>   Cannot Save As PDF (various reasons)
>   Not having Microsoft Word 16.0 object library

Is there any other errors I should be catching?

how do I deal with the `Not having Microsoft Word 16.0 object library`?

Comment: @`Not having Microsoft Word 16.0 object library` This has to do with how you bind, see [early binding vs late binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/245115) for more information.

Comment: I thought so. I'm usually a big early binder, but I suppose I can change to late for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be writing this - I know it's not the answer your looking for, but my experience has been that it is not possible to create an exhaustive list of errors that might occur... especially user errors.

Nevertheless... here are some more to add to your list:

- Check if template or other source document is already opened by someone else
- Check if directory exists (if different to the one being pulled from)
- Try to lock down as much as possible for user... let them only access that which they absolutely need to

Comment: Haha, that's pretty much what I was expecting... You can never predict everything, but as long as I get as many as possible I should be good. Thanks for the extras.

Do you know anything about the object library? should I be using late binding instead?

Comment: As far as I know the Object Library travels with the file if you have added a reference to it in the VBE. So I think it wouldn't matter if it is early or late binding... but I'm not the authority on that topic. Maybe someone else can weigh in on it.

Comment: I checked into this a bit futher. Only the reference travels with the file, not the library itself (as I claimed in my prior comment).